Can I top an avocado tree?
I live in zone 7, but I decided to get a pair of avocado trees (zone 9). So I have to grow them indoors with grow lights half the year. However, by the end of this summer, the plants will outgrow my house. Can I top them without causing real danger to their survival?

Yes, and AFAIK it is still recommended for outdoor cultivation (on snowy region I think). But you will get a bushy shape, so maybe also not so good for indoor. On the other hand, you do not have other options, but going South ;-)
